# How much does the magnetic force change in a solenoid with the distance between turns?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, inductance

I was looking for answer in my physics book and in Internet but not. I guess that more distance should be an smaller magnetic field but I do not know how much.

[image: The homework]

Comment: It scales roughly with 1/L. If you want to maximize the force, you need to make the magnet short. More importantly, you need a magnetic return path. Look at the cross section of lifting magnets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The magnetic field of a solenoid is:
$$
\mathbf B = \mu_0 in\mathbf{\hat k}
$$

Where $i$ is the current, and $\mu_0$ the magnetic permeability. This $n$ is the average number of spirals per unit length. This means, the average gap you mentioned is $1/n$.